# Migrate the identity local sql to an existing database on azure

Tags: azure, identity

I am sort of new to MVC, as it has been a few years since I used it.

I created a new site with individual passwords option selected.  The wizard created a local database for me, and uses code first to create the database and table for identity management.
I tried changing the connection string to be the same as my entityframework connection string, and that did nothing, even after I ran the app.   In fact, it seemed to have no effect, and somehow it still had access to the local db version.

**How do I point the existing code first tables to build a new set of tables on my existing azure database, and then use those tables going forward?**

Comment: My site is asp.net

Comment: I found the answer to this question and tried to post it, but was not able to do so.  Apparently the last time I was online (two years ago) and I asked about the Microsoft Bot framework, someone thought it was a "fake question" whatever that is, and reported me.  So, I am prevented from posting answers.  Sorry, I know others have this question and I tried to post what I found.